# How to remove Media Center from Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center, downgrade

I bought 2 Windows 8 upgrades, 1 for my PC and 1 for my notebook. I added Windows Media Center to my notebook using the free offer in November (side note: the key was emailed to me within 5 minutes, I see many people have been complaining that it takes a few days).

Today I decided to add WMC to my PC as well, so I went onto the Microsoft website, same like last time, and I received the email within a few minutes. Once I added WMC, entered the key and the computer rebooted, my activation is now broken:

> This product key is already being used on another PC. Try a different key or buy a new one.

After rereading the product key email, I realised that the WMC key was exactly the same as the one I had received in November for my notebook (I used the same email, i.e. my Microsoft account Outlook email, for both). I didn't think this would be a problem, as on [Microsoft's feature pack page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ZA/windows-8/feature-packs) it states:

> ...is limited to five licenses per customer per promotion.

So then I decided, I'll just remove WMC from my PC and go back to Windows 8 Pro. So I turned off the WMC feature, PC restarted, activation still broken because my key has been replaced. I then tried to activate it with my original Pro key. The error it gave was that this key cannot be used with this version of Windows, as it is now `Windows 8 Pro with Media Center` and not `Windows 8 Pro` anymore.

I've searched a bit and it seems the only way to remove it is do a clean install. I tried the [Windows 8 Downgrade Helper](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/36726-UpDown8-Windows-8-Upgrade-Downgrade-Helper), which told me I was already running Win 8 Pro when I tried to downgrade, and that I was running Win 8 Pro with Media center when I tried the other option.

To sum up: How do I remove Windows Media Center from Windows 8 Pro without having to do a clean install?

Comment: Have you tried getting a second (different) key for Media Center, if you have two Win8 keys, you should be able to get two WMC keys, maybe use a different email address.

Comment: The thing is, I honestly don't want WMC on the PC now, I just want to remove it. And if they say that I can get up to 5 keys, why are they simply resending me the same key?

Comment: Here's a somewhat complicated way of downgrading your copy of Windows 8: http://www.tech-stew.com/post/2012/09/07/How-to-downgrade-from-Windows-8-MCE-to-Windows-8-Pro.aspx Looks like a pain to do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-Edition is not supported with /online - only usable on offline images

On my system, there is no sign of a restore point (surprising) but it is only a short while since I did the addition (earlier today) and I certainly haven't removed any restore points/cleaned up.

So I don't think the above answer works.

Comment: I also noticed that there was no restore point, so I ended up reinstalling and just leaving WMC completely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

1. Edit Registry
2. Run setup file

Or as you can see in [this tutorial](http://lukesdyer.info/techie-tricks/how-to-downgrade-from-windows-8-professional-media-center-to-windows-8-professional/):

> 1. Go to your Windows Registry and locate : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
> 2. Change EditionID(Professional) and ProductName(Windows 8 Pro) values
> 3. Close Registry, Restart Computer
> 4. Download the Windows 8 Setup.exe file from [the following link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only).
> 5. Enter your valid Windows 8 Professional key that you purchased from Microsoft.
> 6. Run the install and choose to keep all existing apps and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command from an elevated command prompt:

```
Dism /Online /Set-Edition:Professional
```

if it doesn't work, try to use the system restore point which is created before the upgrade.