# Windows 8 Pro with Media Center - Upgrade problems

Tags: windows-8, windows-media-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Media Center from Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/523404/how-to-remove-media-center-from-windows-8)

Microsoft were recently giving away [FREE serial keys to add Media Center to Windows 8 Pro](http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/2013/01/25/how-to-add-media-center-and-dvd-playback-to-windows-8-pro-for-free/), but I missed the boat. A friend offered to give me one of the spare keys they'd gotten for free from MS, and so I decided to give it a shot. The "Upgrade Windows" screen said the key was valid, so I proceeded and Windows quickly installed Media Center to my copy of *Windows 8 Pro*.

Unfortunately, on reboot, it then decided that the key had been activated too many times (arg! so much for a "spare" key!), and now my copy of *Windows 8 Pro* is no longer activated... *at all!*

[image]

I've tried re-entering my valid serial for *Windows 8 Pro*, but Windows had apparently decided I have a copy of *Windows 8 Pro with Media Center*, which is different than plain old *Windows 8 Pro* -- and so my old key wasn't valid.

[image]

I've gone into Add/Remove Features of Windows 8 and uninstalled Media Center, but Windows *still* considers itself to be this *new* version of Windows 8, no longer covered by my valid *Windows 8 Pro* key. (Why can't I "downgrade" back to *Windows 8 Pro*, seeing how I never *actually* upgraded to *Windows 8 Pro with Media Center*...?)

I wouldn't mind buying an upgrade key from *Windows 8 Pro* to *Windows 8 Pro with Media Center*, but even that is proving difficult:

[image]

What can I do to remedy this situation?

Comment: According to the email I got from Microsoft, they says the free keys are only valid till 2013-01-31.

Comment: Did you try to reactivate the Media center key?

Comment: @Karan The link I found is not particularly great. For a start, it wipes a lot of your applications and settings. Also, the phone numbers you linked to are for product activation, not technical support, nor sales, so I'm not sure they're that useful :(

Comment: @PratyushNalam How would one go about doing that?

Comment: @JohnnyW I suppose Windows didn't automatically activate it. Just activate it again from the activation screen

Answer (score 1):

I activated it successfully over the phone... Phew!

Comment: That's cool :) Sometimes, web activation fails due to any number of reasons. The key is to do it again :)

Comment: And didn't I suggest the phone numbers for activation above? :)

Comment: @Karan You did! you should have put it in an answer :) Why was this closed as a duplicate when it's clearly different, btw?

Comment: @Karan And why did you vote to close this question as an "exact duplicate" when it's clearly not?

Comment: When you asked what you could do to remedy the situation, the link showing how to remove Media Center *is* a valid answer (and clearly, others agreed with me). It was only later that you commented saying removal of (any?) apps/settings was not tolerable. If you disagree, you can always flag for it to be reopened.