# how to remove Media Center Edition from windows 8.1 Pro which will allow it to be reinstalled

Tags: windows-8.1, audio-recording

Actually I have a problem with MCE.  Audio is inconsistent - when recording it sometimes includes audio and other times it wont.  I felt that if I reinstalled MCE the problem would be resolved.  So my question is can I uninstall MCE and reinstall it on Windows 8.1 and how to do that.  Then reinstall MCE again and see if it resolves my problem?

Comment: Reinstalling is very unlikely to solve that issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Media Center from Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/523404/how-to-remove-media-center-from-windows-8)

Comment: Once Media Center has been installed on Windows 8, you must reinstall Windows 8, in order to remove it.  This is due to the fact while Media Center is installed, the licensed Windows product, is actually identified as `Windows 8 Professional with Media Center`  There are three editions of Windows 8.  Windows 8, Windows 8 Professional, and Windows 8 Professional with Media Center

Comment: You might be try an application that is still being maintained, such as Kodi, https://kodi.tv/download